# A cool way of doing Z-index for XNA components?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to render some elements in my game. First, I render the textures (the textures of the textboxes themselves etc). Then I render the primitives (borders around controls etc). Then I render the text.

However, by doing so, this gives a weird result in my user-interface when showing tooltips (by hovering over a textfield), as seen in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Due to the order of drawing, borders around the window are drawn after textures, which (for the tooltip that appears when my mouse is over the textfield) makes it look weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If these are each separate `DrawableGameComponents`, you should set the [`DrawOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.draworder.aspx) property of each component so that they draw in the correct order.

To make it more manageable as you add more components, the `DrawOrder` should be an `enum`:

```
/* DisplayLayer.cs */
public enum DisplayLayer
{
    Background, //back-layer
    Particles,
    Player,
    MenuBack,
    MenuFront //front-layer
}

public class MyComponent : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public MyComponent(Game game) : base(game)
    {
        this.DrawOrder = (int)DisplayLayer.Background;
    }

    /* etc. */
}
```

---

If this is all being drawn within a single `DrawableGameComponent`, then you should take @Andrew's advice and simply draw them in the correct order.  If for some reason you can't do that, you can still have the clarity of `enum`s when using `layerDepth` by simply normalizing the value of the `enum` to be between 0 and 1:

```
/* DisplayLayer.cs */
public enum DisplayLayer
{
    MenuFront, //front-layer
    MenuBack,
    Player,
    Particles,
    Background, //back-layer
    MAX_LAYER   //Do not use this as a layer
}

public void Draw()
{
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront);
    foreach(Thingy thingy in thingys)
        spriteBatch.Draw(/* blah blah */, (float)thingy.DisplayLayer/(float)DisplayLayer.MAX_LAYER);
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

*(The ordering of the `enum` is reversed because `layerDepth` uses lower numbers for the front-layer rather than the back-layer)*

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx

```
public void Draw (
         Texture2D texture,
         Vector2 position,
         Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
         Color color,
         float rotation,
         Vector2 origin,
         Vector2 scale,
         SpriteEffects effects,
         float layerDepth
)
```

**layerDepth**
The depth of a layer. By default, 0 represents the front layer and 1 represents a back layer. Use SpriteSortMode if you want sprites to be sorted during drawing.

For example you have: Form, and in the form labels, buttons 
So for children elements you can add to layerDepth some value 
For example: Form A have children: Form B and some buttons, Form B have only button 
Form A - 1.0 
Buttons in form A - 1.5 
Form B in Form A - 1.5 
Buttons in form B - 2

For Dialogs - you can store some bigger value

Comment: A few caveats for this method: the valid range of `layerDepth` (I'm reasonably sure) is 0 to 1, so you'd have to stay inside that range. Additionally all drawing will need to be done within the one sprite batch (between `Begin` and `End`). Finally: it is worth pointing out that this method provides no performance benefit over simply drawing things in the correct order in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to give the simple and fairly obvious answer, and that is **just draw everything in the correct order in the first place**.

To mock-up an example of what I mean:

```
// Assuming you have sorted windowList by Z-order, using one of the many
// existing sorting mechanisms provided by the framework such as List<T>.Sort().
foreach(var window in windowList)
    window.Draw();

// in your Window class:
public void Draw()
{
    this.DrawBackground();
    this.DrawBorders();
    this.DrawText();
}
```

Is there a particular, compelling reason why you are not already drawing your windows in this way?

Comment: I would guess that, as he states in his question, it is because he is doing both SpriteBatch and primitive calls, and hence he wants to batch them together, which is not really a bad idea.
I seem to recall that even so, the SpriteBatch will batch all calls anyway so I'm pretty sure tour option would be the same perf wise.

It also makes more sense.

Comment: @3nixios I would guess his reason is for performance too - but I'd then immediately suggest that it's premature optimisation. Is his GUI really performing so badly? And is consolidating batches really the correct choice of optimisation? Also `SpriteBatch` cannot batch past a texture change - so my method is potentially slower than his method if his implementation is properly optimised.

Comment: And his method is viable - by the way. But it's difficult to implement correctly - including forming it into a good answer. So it's probably not worth the effort for the small performance gain - and therefore it would be the wrong answer to give. (The short version is: use the Z-buffer.)

Comment: I totally agree :)

Comment: I don't follow why the above approach prevents you from batching all your `SpriteBatch` operations together.  Just modify the draw methods to accept the `SpriteBatch` as a parameter.  Then, in the base-most "Draw" method, first call `SpriteBatch.Begin()` -- then call "Draw" on the Windows (passing in `SpriteBatch`, which they will use and pass into each child) -- then after the loop, in the base-most "Draw" method, call `SpriteBatch.End()`. . .  (My $0.02: I bet he's not using objects and the whole thing is probably a big procedural mess in his main `Game` class.)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 That's how I'd probably do things, just to make the code neat (although it gets more complicated if you have to start using scissor rectangles to make scrollable regions). But to get the performance benefit of batching, you have to also reduce the number of texture swaps by using a texture atlas, and for a UI this may not be worth the effort.