# XNA - Spritebatch Drawing Order

Tags: xna, c#, spritebatch

I'm new in this and I'm making XNA game. I have problem with the `spritebatch` drawing order. To be explained : I click button to open inventory and I need all drawing to be behind my inventory layout. But problem is that I don't know how to do this because in my draw method I cannot change my drawing hierarchy, as all the stuff need to be drawn before the inventory is drawn.

Is there a way to set up a drawing order? Or is there a way to dynamically move one particular `spritebatch` up in drawing hierarchy?

Comment: Did you *try anything*? [First search result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618343/xna-draw-order-not-working-right) for *xna spritebatch draw order*.

Comment: Ironically *this* is now the top search result.

Comment: Appears to be functionally the same as this older question: [A cool way of doing Z-index for XNA components?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13395/a-cool-way-of-doing-z-index-for-xna-components)

Answer (score 2):

You could have a `DisplayManager` which contains some "layers", let's say you want 3 layers, `bottom`, `middle` and `top`. These layers aka `lists` contains the instances of the `IDisplay` objects. `IDisplay` is an *interface* with a `Draw` function.
The `DisplayManager` itself has an `Update` or `Draw` function, however you name it, and you call it between the `SpriteBatch's` `Begin` and `End` function.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
DisplayManager.Update(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();
...
//In the DisplayManager class:
private static List<IDisplay> top = new List<IDisplay>();
private static List<IDisplay> middle = new List<IDisplay>();
private static List<IDisplay> bottom = new List<IDisplay>();
...
//In the DisplayManager class:
public static void Update(SpriteBatch batch){
    for (i = 0; i < bottom.Count; i++)
    {
        bottom[i].Draw(batch);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < middle.Count; i++)
    {
        middle[i].Draw(batch);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < top.Count; i++)
    {
        top[i].Draw(batch);
    }
}
```

Note the draw order in the Update function, first draw the "bottom" layer, then the middle and the top.

Comment: I would rather use Dictionary<int, List<IDisplay>> where key is draw order.